# Make loop alphabetical

Tags: loop

I have a simple loop but it returns it in any order.  What I'm looking for is to alphabetize the loop. I've tried a few different things but Can't seem to get it to work.

```
<?php
 // Start the loop.
 while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();

    // Include the page content template.
    get_template_part( 'content', 'grid-projects' );
 // End the loop.
 endwhile;
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is what worked for me.  works a treat.

```
$child_pages = new WP_Query( array(
  'orderby'     => 'name',
  'order'       => 'ASC',
  'cat'         => '41'
) );
while ( $child_pages->have_posts() ) : $child_pages->the_post();
  get_template_part( 'content', 'grid-projects' );
endwhile;
wp_reset_postdata();
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to alter the query and add the `orderby` argument specified as `name`. I would go for the `pre_get_posts` action ([see documentation](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/pre_get_posts)) with some conditional tags to select the query for the right page.

For example:

```
function change_posts_order($query) {
  if($query->is_home() && $query->is_main_query()) { // edit to match the desired page
     $query->set('orderby', 'name');
     $query->set('order', 'ASC');
  }
}
add_action('pre_get_posts', 'change_posts_order');
```

Comment: Your answer is probably right, unfortunatly I'm unable to use your example with my code.  I can see the structure, but being a newbie I'm unable to modify it to work. thanks though.

Comment: I'm going to need an example using my code with it, I learn by seeing a working example that I drop in.

Comment: The code from your OP can stay the same. You just have to add my code to `functions.php` and edit it so it matches the page where your posts should be alphabetical.